# MarkLogic: Having facet results be case-insensitive

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a constraint based on an XML path range index, that is returning facet values for different types of letter casing:

```
<facet name="myFacet" type="xs:string">
    <facet-value name="test TEST" count="1"/>
    <facet-value name="Test Test" count="3"/>
</facet>
```

I want my facet values to be case insensitive, to where the above I would have 4 results for "Test Test". Is there a way of easily setting this in the options, the below I have is not working:

```
<constraint name="myFacet">
    <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
        <path-index>/path/to/data</path-index>
        <word>
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        </word>
    </range>
</constraint>
```

Without manually lowercasing each item in the field in the data itself, is there a way to achieve this with a search option I can pass into the constraint?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a string index that uses a collation which includes the case-insensitive flag. You then refer to that string index as usual, but with the extra collation.

I recommend looking at the Admin ui, open the path indexes page of your database, create one of type string, and look for the collation builder button. It should pop up a little wizard that helps you compose the collation you need.

HTH!